# Is it possible that Precision-Recall curve or a ROC curve is a horizontal line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, roc, precision-recall

I am working on a binary classification task on imbalanced data.

Since the accuracy is not so meaningful in this case.
I use Scikit-Learn to compute the Precision-Recall curve and ROC curve in order to evaluate the model performance.

But I found both of the curves would be a horizontal line when I use Random Forest with a lot of estimators, it also happens when I use a SGD classifier to fit it.

The ROC chart is as following:

[image]

And the Precision-Recall chart:

[image]

Since Random Forest behaves randomly, I don't get a horizontal line in every run, sometimes I also get a regular ROC and PR curve. But the horizontal line is much more common.

Is this normal? Or I made some mistakes in my code?

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
try:
    scores = classifier.decision_function(X_test)
except:
    scores = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]

precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(Y_test, scores, pos_label=1)
average_precision = average_precision_score(Y_test, scores)

plt.plot(recall, precision, label='area = %0.2f' % average_precision, color="green")
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('Recall')
plt.ylabel('Precision')
plt.title('Precision Recall Curve')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

Comment: it looks a bit too good to be ture. :-) Could you please upload your sample data  file via dropbox sharelink or google driver?

Comment: Take the time and think about what the plots actually tell you. You basically performed perfect predictions on the test set. `Is this normal?` No. Often problems tackled with machine learning techniques are much harder. Perfect predictions are usually not possible.  `Or did I make some mistakes in my code?` In your code? Probably not. In your testing? Maybe. We don't know. I would suggest trying a cross validation instead. Maybe your problem is very easy to learn. Maybe your test set is problematic. A cross validation will show that.

Comment: Thank you guys!  It is really helping. I will try cross validation. I will upload the data if I still can't get regular curves.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161314/can-a-precision-recall-curve-or-a-roc-curve-be-horizontal

Comment: Cel: It is truly the problem of the selection of testing data. I happen to choose an easy set of testing. That's why I got a horizontal line. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you perfectly separate the data into two piles, then you go vertically from zero to 1 true-positive-rate without any false positives (the vertical line) as your threshold passes over your pile of true positives, then from 0 to 1 false-positive-rate as your threshold passes over your pile of true negatives.

If you can get the same ROC curve from a test set, you are golden. If you can get the same ROC curve evaluated on 5 different k-fold cross validation test sets, you are platinum.

Comment: I got the regular curves after 10 times cross validation Stratified Shuffle Split.  Thanks you for this great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Along with the other answers, it's possible that you have duplicated your label as a feature in the dataset. Thus, when sampling occurs in RF, you don't always get that feature as a predictor and get a "normal-looking" ROC curve (i.e. the other features can't predict the label exactly); when you do get the duplicated label/feature in the sample, your model has 100% accuracy by definition.

SGD can have the same issue, in a way that linear regression would fail. In a linear regression, you'd have a singular/near-singular matrix and the estimation would fail. With SGD, since you're re-estimating based on each next point arriving, the math doesn't fail (though, your model will still be suspect).

Comment: I don't have the "Answer Feature" among my features, but this is still a very good insight, Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

The other 2 answers are only sufficient conditions of seeing a horizontal line (aka they are the possible causes of a horizontal line, but they are not the only possiblities). Here is the necessary and sufficient conditions:

If you see a horizontal line in PR-curve, it must be at the top and it means examples in the threshold range are all TPs. And the longer the line, the more TP (because a longer line has a larger recall).

Proof:

Let's denote "TP" as true positive and "PP" as predicted positives, and therefore precision = TP/PP.

A horizontal line means recall increases by some amount and precision unchanged. Let's discuss these 2 things separately:

1. recall increases by some amount ->

- TP increases by some amount
- Suppose TP increases by the smallest amount, 1. Suppose x is the amount of increase in PP. By definition x>=1.

2. precision unchanged ->

- (TP+1)/(PP+x)=TP/PP
  Solving this for x we have x=TP/PP. Because precision = TP/PP <=1, and we just said "by definition x>=1", x has to be 1.

This means both the increase in TP and PP is 1, i.e. only positive examples are added. Since x=TP/PP, we have precision TP/PP=1 as well. QED.